# Range user input does not show proper output in SQL

Tags: sql

The `Check_No` column datatype is `VARCHAR2`, `Check_No` column could have `Alphanumeric(without uppercase and lowercase)` values.

And I want to input a `range` parameter.

```
> SELECT Check_No FROM CHECK_ITEM
> WHERE Check_No BETWEEN '&From_Check_No_' AND '&To_Check_No_'

input- 
From_Check_No_: 1
To_Check_No_: 3
```

result shows like this:

```
| Check_No |
------------
| 1        |
| 111121   |
| 111122   |
| 15       |
| 2        |
| 20       |
| 2101002  |
| 22       |
| 3        |
```

but my expected outcome is:

```
| Check_No |
------------
| 1        |
| 2        |
| 3        |
```

Comment: `varchar2` isnt a data typ in SQL Server. But th problem is that you are storing numerical data as a strong based data type and expecting it to act like a numerical value: it won't. `'12'` is **less than** `'2'`.

Comment: Oracle and SQL Server are two completely different products. Oracle SQL Developer is a client tool, not the database itself and doesn't affect the database's SQL syntax

Comment: What should be an order for `A10` and `A0011`?

Comment: Do you also want to filter with alphanumeric inputs?

Answer (score 0):

Change Check_No's datatype to an int oppose to varchar.

Varchar won't treat characters as integers but like characters so if you had WHERE Check_No BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C' it would get return
A
AAAAAB
BABB
C